# strange behavior of query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table below:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| category_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| created_on  | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| updated_on  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I needed to delete some records according to the date created and executed a set of queries:

```
mysql> select created_on from categories limit 10;
+---------------------+
| created_on          |
+---------------------+
| 2013-01-14 09:26:21 |
| 2012-08-15 11:18:38 |
| 2012-09-06 06:44:46 |
| 2012-09-06 23:27:14 |
```

then

```
mysql> select date('2013-01-14 09:26:21');
+-----------------------------+
| date('2013-01-14 09:26:21') |
+-----------------------------+
| 2013-01-14                  |
+-----------------------------+
```

and finally I got:

```
mysql> select DATE('created_on') from categories limit 10;
+--------------------+
| DATE('created_on') |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
| NULL               |
| NULL               |
| NULL               |
```

As you can see the date wasn't converted correctly. In about 10 minutes is worked ok:

```
mysql> select date(created_on) from categories limit 10;
+------------------+
| date(created_on) |
+------------------+
| 2013-01-14       |
| 2012-08-15       |
| 2012-09-06       |
| 2012-09-06       |
```

I'm sure that the data were intact while I was running the queries.

So my question:
 
Can anybody explain why date function showed different results on the same input?

Comment: The input wasn't the same.  one time you told it to  cast the text 'created_on' to a date field; resulting in Null for each record as it couldn't do it.  The other time you told it to actually use a timestamp field and return JUSt the date portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use::

```
select DATE(created_on) from categories limit 10;
```

By using the inverted comma, you are asking the database to treat `'created_on'` as parameter, and since it cannot be converted to date type, you are getting null

Comment: thank you, I was able to see what's wrong with your edit on my own :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select DATE('created_on') from categories limit 10;
```

String versus column:

```
select DATE(created_on) from categories limit 10;
```